# Should SqlConnections be long or shortlived with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a few DbContextes that connects to the same database in the same application.

I noticed that EF6 has a new constructor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696604(v=vs.113).aspx

My question is then, lets say I hook up my DI framework to create a SqlConnection for each request and passes this to each of the DbContexts with this new constructor instead, would that be the correct way to go about it? Or should the Sql connection be longlived and not per request?

```
    public async Task<SqlConnection> GetOpenedConnectionAsync()
    {
        _connection = new SqlConnection(_config.AscendDataBaseConnectionString);
        await _connection.OpenAsync(_cancel.Token);

        return _connection;
    }
```

Register above per application lifetime or per request lifetime?

Comment: If you're have not performance problems already, I would advise don't manage SQL connections manually. There's the SQL connections pool in ADO.NET, and it works. Just try to dispose `DbContext`'s as soon as possible.

Comment: the question was more from a "I want to understand what happens" than "I want to optimize it". Does dbContext dispose close connection? or as you are hinting, do EF keep a pool of connections such that many dbcontexts share the same connection?

Comment: Normally `DbContext` creates/opens the connection when it is created, and closes the one when it is disposed. But `SqlConnection` is a wrapper about the pool, so real connection remains opened for some time. The next `DbContext` that will be created with the same connection string, will use this existing connection. But a few `DbContext`'s creates a few connections at the same time. Of course you can manage connections manually, just append `Pooling=false` to connection string, and use specialized constructor of `DbContext`.

Comment: So the snippet i provided actually is also using the connection pool since its just using SqlConnection wrapper. conclussion is though that its not needed to give a SqlConnection to dbcontext, because dbcontext will actually use the same connection if same connection string is used. Do this also hold true if a real connection string is given to dbcontext instead of config connectionstring name.

Comment: Yes. you're right. It's more effectively to open a connection and keep it open as long, as possible, but it's hard to do correctly in web apps, especially in asynchronous web apps. So it's easier just to create the `DbContext`, (asynchronously) use it, and then dispose. The connection pool will do all the hard work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your use case but in general i would highly discourage Singleton scope.

Generally the cost of creating a new connection and tearing it down is low, unless there is a long packet delay between Server and Db (e.g. mobile) but if servers are close this is < 5ms.

If lets say you have 1 database, used by a thousand servers (load balancing or whatever), if all those servers always kept an open connection you may run into issues, but  if you had each one open and close connections as and when needed, this probably would work.

If you have 1 database,  and 1 or 2 servers, you could have a single connection (to save a small amount of time per request) but there are pitfalls and i would HIGHLY discourage it because:

- If you open a transaction, no other query will be able to run until that transaction finishes as there can only be 1 transaction at any time per connection. E.g. User A tries to list all Customers (takes 5 seconds), this means no other query can run until you get all the customers back.
- If a transactions gets opened, and for whatever reason it does not commit, you will basically loos complete connectivity to the database until that transaction gets rolled back/committed, which may or may not happen.